# Is there any difference between git add -u and git add --all

Tags: git

I found that most of the dev are using "git add --all" instead of "git add -u",
Can you please help me out?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)? Both options are explained there very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/) you can see the differences

[`git add -u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add--u)

> Update the index just where it already has an entry matching
>   `<pathspec>`. This removes as well as modifies index entries to match
>   the working tree, but adds no new files.
>
> If no `<pathspec>` is given when `-u` option is used, all tracked files in
>   the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit
>   the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).

[`git add --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add---all)

> Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching  but also where the index already has an entry.
>   This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working
>   tree.
>
> If no `<pathspec>` is given when `-A` option is used, all files in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the
>   update to the current directory and its subdirectories).

Comment: Thanks for the details about "--all" and "-u" dippas

Comment: @LalitOnclick no problem :)

Comment: why is that link for? I have that link in my answer ! It is supposed to answer something about downvote?

Answer (score 0):

git add -u  **add only tracked files**

git add --all **add tracked and untracked files**